# creating signals based on current and prior time periods

Tags: python, trading

I'm trying to write a trading algo and I am very new to python.

Lots of things are easy to understand but I get lost easily.  I have a strategy I want to use, but the coding is getting in the way.

I want to create two moving averages and when they cross I want that to be a signal.

The part im I am currently struggling with is also including information about the prior period.

When
`MovingAverage1( last 10 candles ) == MovingAverage2( Last 20 candles )`,
that's a signal,
but is it a buy or sell?

When
`MovingAVerage1( last 10 candles after skipping most recent ) >  MovingAverage2( last 10 candles after skipping most recent )`
then sell.

Here is what I've got so far, where the MA-s I am using are being simplified for this question:

```
class MyMACrossStrategy (Strategy):
    """    
    Requires:
    symbol - A stock symbol on which to form a strategy on.
    bars - A DataFrame of bars for the above symbol.
    short_window - Lookback period for short moving average.
    long_window - Lookback period for long moving average."""

def __init__(self, symbol, bars, short_window=4, long_window=9):
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.bars = bars

    self.short_window = short_window
    self.long_window = long_window

    # Function Helper for indicators


def fill_for_noncomputable_vals(input_data, result_data):
    non_computable_values = np.repeat(
        np.nan, len(input_data) - len(result_data)
        )
    filled_result_data = np.append(non_computable_values, result_data)
    return filled_result_data

def simple_moving_average(data, period):
"""
Simple Moving Average.
Formula:
SUM(data / N)
"""
catch_errors.check_for_period_error(data, period)
# Mean of Empty Slice RuntimeWarning doesn't affect output so it is
# supressed
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
    sma = [np.mean(data[idx-(period-1):idx+1]) for idx in range(0, len(data))]
sma = fill_for_noncomputable_vals(data, sma)
return sma


def hull_moving_average(data, period):
    """
    Hull Moving Average.
    Formula:
    HMA = WMA(2*WMA(n/2) - WMA(n)), sqrt(n)
    """
    catch_errors.check_for_period_error(data, period)
    hma = wma(
        2 * wma(data, int(period/2)) - wma(data, period), int(np.sqrt(period))
        )
    return hma


def generate_signals(self):
    """Returns the DataFrame of symbols containing the signals
    to go long, short or hold (1, -1 or 0)."""
    signals = pd.DataFrame(index=self.bars.index)
    signals['signal'] = 0.0

    # Create the set of moving averages over the 
    # respective periods
    signals['Fast_Line'] = sma(bars['Close'], self.short_window)
    signals['Slow_line'] = hma(bars['Close'], self.long_window)
    signals1['Fast_Line'] = sma(bars['Close'], self.short_window[-1])
    signals1['Slow_line'] = hma(bars['Close'], self.long_window[-1])

    # Create a 'signal' (invested or not invested) when the short moving average crosses the long
    # moving average, but only for the period greater than the shortest moving average window
    signals['signal'][self.short_window:] = np.where(signals['Fast_Line'][self.short_window:] 
        > signals['Slow_line'][self.short_window:], 1.0, 0.0)   

    # Take the difference of the signals in order to generate actual trading orders
    signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff()   

    if signals['Fast_Line'] = signals['Slow_Line'] and ...
    return signals
```

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: You might want to revise the code, as the python code requires proper positional formatting, which was not present in the original post. Feel free to edit the Question and correct + complete the MCVE-code so as to run.

Comment: thank you for the comment.  i think ive just realized something different needs to happen anyways.  i do appreciate the review. still learning

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to test your strategy first before using it in live market. You can download the stock data from yahoo finance in csv format. And you can upload with below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('MSFT.csv')
```

once the data is stored in the pandas dataframe data, you can moving average of the Closing price with following code:
if you are planning the crossover strategy

```
sma_days=20
lma_days=50
```

`data['SMA_20']=data['Close'].rolling(window=sma_days,center=False).mean()
data['SMA_50']=data['Close'].rolling(window=lma_days,center=False).mean()
data['SIGNAL']=np.where(data['SMA_20']>data['SMA_50'],'BUY','SELL')`